# CSS: How to apply a background tiled image and a radial gradient over it at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I've seen these answers already: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792494/apply-background-color-and-image-at-the-same-time), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417032/no-repeat-background-image-and-gradient-same-time), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients).

But it didn't help.
My program is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nav9/6VeB7/9/

**Two questions:**
1. Does it make sense to have such background code placed within the `html` tag or the `head` tag instead of inside the `body` tag?
2. How do I get a gradient over the background image? It works fine when I place the background image in the `html` tag and the gradient in the `head` tag, but I want both in the same tag.

The CSS:

```
body 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    /*background: radial-gradient(rgba(45,255,27,0.8), rgba(255,162,12,0.87), rgba(14,12,12,1));*/
    background: radial-gradient(rgba(45,255,27,0.8), rgba(255,162,12,0.87), rgba(14,12,12,1));/*, url("images/starTile.png") repeat;*/
    background-image: url("images/starTile.png") repeat;    
    position: fixed;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles.css">
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the reason it's not a duplicate: I'm trying to repeat the starTile, and the gradient doesn't work when I use `repeat`. But if I use `no-repeat`, I can see the gradient as well as a single starTile image.

```
body
{
    background-image: url('images/starTile.png'), radial-gradient(rgba(45,255,27,0.8), rgba(255,162,12,0.87), rgba(14,12,12,1));
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left center, left top;
    background-size: auto, 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you had actual images in your JSddle

Comment: This - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417032/no-repeat-background-image-and-gradient-same-time gives you your answer. Comma separate ALL of the background properties and do NOT use the shorthand.

Comment: @Paulie_D How do I add actual images to the fiddle? Didn't find any option to do so. I'm new to JSFiddle.

Comment: Also, put your link tag within the head. Also, in your CSS, the background-image rule will have no affect on the first background rule.
@Nav JSFiddle doesn't host images. You need to put them online somewhere first (like a dropbox account).

Comment: @evolutionxbox My link tag was initially in head, but JSFiddle showed me a message asking me to not include the head tag because it is already part of the output.

Comment: @Nav http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172762/adding-images-in-jsfiddle

Comment: @Nav You have to put them online and link them in. I use photobucket.com or use an dummy image site like lorempixel.com

Comment: @Nav: See your fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6VeB7/8/

Comment: Thanks. Added an image URL

Comment: Guys, this isn't a duplicate question, because in my question, I'm trying to repeat the background image, which is what makes the gradient not appear. In the other questions, they're not repeating the background image. I've updated the question with the code.

Comment: So is there no way to do it?